# Signing mixed code assembly

Tags: .net, unmanaged, managed-c++, sign, sn.exe

I have a mixed assambly written in C++ managed and unmanaged. To sign this assembly I use delayed signing with the following Post-build event:

```
sn -R $(TargetPath) $(ProjectDir)Fischer.snk
```

This works without any problems on my own PC (VS2010 english, Windows XP 32Bit).

If I transfer this project on another PC (VS2010 german, Win7 32Bit), this build step failes with an error message.

```
Fehler   1          error MSB3073: Der Befehl "sn -R C:\Daten\APRGX\DotNet\VisualData\Master3DControlClasses\Project\Debug\Fischer.APRGX.MathAlg.Native.dll c:\Daten\APRGX\DotNet\MathAlg\Native\Fischer.snk :VCEnd" wurde mit dem Code 1 beendet.         C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets            113       6          Fischer.APRGX.MathAlg.Native
```

What can be the reason?

Edit:
Starting the tool in command prompt it says:

```
"C:\Daten\APRGX\DotNet\VisualData\Master3DControlClasses\Project\Debug\Fischer.APRGX.MathAlg.Native.dll" stellt keine Assembly mit einem starken Namen dar.
```

It says that the dll doesn't have a strong name. I don't understand that, because the same project builds without problems on my first machine.

Comment: Type the command by hand from the Visual Studio Command Prompt to get a better diagnostic.

Comment: -R is used for *resigning* an assembly.  It must have been delay signed before.  Seems that wasn't done.  /DELAYSIGN linker option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
The problem was that on my original PC I'm using VS2010 and on the second PC I'm using VS2010 SP1.

VS2010 without SP1 stores in project file:

```
    <Link>
  <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
  <AdditionalDependencies>
  </AdditionalDependencies>
  <KeyFile>$(ProjectDir)Fischer.snk</KeyFile>
  <DelaySign>true</DelaySign>
</Link>
```

VS2010 with SP1 stores:

```
    <LinkKeyFile>$(ProjectDir)Fischer.snk</LinkKeyFile>
<LinkDelaySign>true</LinkDelaySign>
```

So VS2010 with SP1 igonores the /DELAYSIGN option that was set without SP1. And so sn.exe couldn't sign the assembly.

Installing SP1 on my original PC and setting the delay sign option again solved the problem.